# How to Delete each line of the file from Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I have file with the content of

> 123
>   234
>   345

I am using a `foreach` loop to read each line of the file.

I have a requirement like: I would like to remove each line of the file inside the `foreach` loop.

Is there anyway to remove line of the file inside foreach loop?

Here's what I've tried:

```
$source1 = "Y:\New Documents\test.txt"
foreach ($line in Get-Content $source1) {
    $find = $line
    (Get-Content $source1).replace($find,"") |
        Set-Content $source1
}
```

I am able to clear the content of file and I don't know how to make file with zero size.

Comment: And removing each line will render you an empty file as an output. What's exactly are you looking for. Please elaborate.

Comment: lets say i want read 123 from file then i will do other stuffs then want to remove 123 from file and i want to go like that and finally i want empty file as a output

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh I *think* what they want is `-replace`, but the "question" is so open-ended and lazy that I'm not spending any more cycles on processing it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @TheIncorrigible,i spent to much time but i am not geeting any solution for this case so please take it seriously

Comment: @Rab If you want your question taken seriously, take it seriously yourself.  StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.  Show what work you've already done yourself **in your question** and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - Yeah true. I could just wonder why it is required in the first place.
Rab, can you show us what have you tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: $source1 = "Y:\New Documents\test.txt"

foreach($line in Get-Content $source1)

{ 

$find=$line

(Get-Content $source1).replace($find,"")|Set-Content $source1

 }                                                                                                                            I tried this way i am able to clear the content of file and i don't know how to make file with zero size

Comment: `Clear-Content $file`?

Comment: @Ansgar yes we can use Clear-Content to clear the file but waht i want is i want to remove 1st line of the file and want to shift second line into first then want to remove that line and so on.......finally i want file output with zero size

Comment: What? Why? If you're going to reduce the file size to zero anyway all shuffling around of its content is for naught.

Comment: @Ansgar: scenario is i want to read first line of the file then want to do some stuffs then i want to send that data to business and want to delete that line and want to go into another line,process will be repeated again

Comment: Why would you delete each line?  Just read the file, process it, then clear it.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible,that is the business requirement

Comment: @Rab The business is wrong.  There's no logical reason to do that.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible, they just want to remove line from file after getting that line,by the way is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called "truncating a file". PowerShell has a cmdlet for that:

```
Clear-Content $source1
```

If you want to do some processing first: do that first, *then* clear the file:

```
Get-Content $source1 | ForEach-Object {
    # do stuff with content of $source1
}

Clear-Content $source1
```

If there is a situation where you want to process the content and keep lines under one circumstance or the other you could collect the lines that should be kept in a variable and write that back to the file:

```
$remains = Get-Content $source1 | ForEach-Object {
    if (<# some condition or other #>) {
        # do stuff with matching lines
    } else {
        # output back to pipeline
        $_
    }
}

# write $remains back to file if it's not empty, otherwise clear file
if ($remains) {
    $remains | Set-Content $source1
} else {
    Clear-Content $source1
}
```